# remove &AFFIL=12345 from defunct Miva URLs and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I dumped Miva and moved to ZenCart.

I've used htaccess to redirect the primary Miva ULRs to all the different products in ZC.

But there are a number of old affiliate URLs floating around that 404 for me.

What rewrite code must I place into htaccess to strip out the &AFFIL=12345 (5-digit number varies) and then redirect the remainder of the string to the new ZenCart URL?

EXAMPLE:

Strip out variable &AFFIL=86758 from:

http://www.standardlegal.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Store_Code=SLcom&Product_Code=SLS508&AFFIL=86758

then forward the click on to:

http://www.standardlegal.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=20

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following rewrite will strip `AFFIL=nnnnn` from the **end** of a query string, but retain the rest of the query string.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:(.*)&)?AFFIL=\d{5}
RewriteRule .* /store/index.php?%1 [L]
```

The condition saves all parameter-value pairs from the query string, if there are any, but does not retain the affiliate parameter and its value.

Note that you need to reference the captured groups from the rewrite condition with a `%`, not an `$` as you would with a rewrite rule.

[Edit]

The following redirect will deal with the example URL change you've given:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Product_Code=SLS508
RewriteRule ^Merchant2/merchant.mvc /store/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=20 [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite condition means that this rule only works for a particular product. The rule requires that rewrite is from the base path on your old site (just in case product code ended up in the URL's of the new site for any reason). I've also added 301 redirect rather than a silent internal redirect as you should be telling your visitors that your URL's have changed.

[/Edit]

As a side note I would not be using Zencart, the code-base is horrible and updates a nightmare. I gave up using it a few years ago and moved to Magento.

Comment: Thanks for answering Dom, but I'm not sure I understand your first sentence in reply. As you can see from the example, there is nothing to 'retain' from the old Miva string -- the URLs and product codes are completely different. I'm not fluent in creating this htaccess code myself and need an example that I can replicate for 20 different products, old format to new...

Comment: BTW, the example I posted above is a real-world one and the two URLs presented are to a matching product in the old cart vs. new. It was easy to create the necessary redirects product-to-product (Miva to ZC), but the &AFFIL=12345 throws a wrench into forwarding the URLs where there is an affiliate ID. So I was hoping there is a way to set up my 20 products to redirect while stripping out many variable affiliate numbers that may appear...

Comment: Your original question was inconstant, you said you just wanted to strip out AFFIL=12345 from the query string and pass the *remainder* of the string to Zencart, but your example showed a completely different URL transformation, where everything was stripped out. Its unclear if your are looking for a single redirect that will work for all products or a a set of redirects, one for each product. I've edited my answer to cover the example redirect you gave.

Comment: Thanks, yes, my stated question did say pass a string but the example showed the need. You bring up a good point in your reply: I was thinking that I needed one 301 redirect for each product (which is what I created for the non-affiliate URLs), but is there a better way that uses only variables? The URLs from each cart are the same for all 20 products (except for the varying AFFIL number), it's just the product number in each that needs change to correctly 301 redirect...

Comment: Dom, I used the code you provided and input the 20+ product IDs into each one, and it works perfectly -- even if an affiliate changed the order of the variables (which I see a few times had happened in Webmaster Tools)! Thank you so much for your help, and I hope this post can help others...